# Копирование файла в буфер обмена

Tags: c#, копирование

Как можно сделать что бы при нажатии на кнопку (в программе) копировался в буфер обмена определенный файл (например текстовый)?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.clipboard, правда работает только на винде, для .net core вроде как только сторонние либы с nuget можно скачивать

Comment: Я видел эту страницу, но не совсем понимаю как это можно реализовать в виде кода, можете подсказать пожалуйста?

Comment: По ссылке есть примеры кода, читайте статью и делайте так, как там сказано